# Conv1D specify output chanels in tensorflow 2.1

Tags: python, deep-learning, tensorflow, cnn, speech-to-text

Hello I'm trying to implement the "Tacotron Towards end to end" paper and in the
`Encoder CBHG - a Conv1D bank of K=16, conv-k-128-ReLU`
“conv-k-c-ReLU” - denotes 1-D convolution
with width k and c output channels with ReLU activation.
And I wanted to ask how exactly I can implement it in Tensorflow 2.1? because in the documentation I haven't seen how to specify the output channels

Reference to the paper: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.10135.pdf

Comment: Hi. Could you add a reference and maybe polish your text to make it more readable? Thanks.

Comment: Hi @oW_ I added a reference

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Conv1D

The parameter **filter** determines the output channel.